# Return multiple values from a function in PHP

Tags: php

I have this function that returns three value when calling it.

```
function GetCashierDetail ($UserID){

    $GetCashierID = "SELECT cashiers_CashierID,cashiers_Total,cashiers_Last_Total
                     FROM `cashiers`
                     WHERE `cashiers_CashierCloseDate` is null and `cashiers_Status`='0'
                     and `cashiers_Delete` = '0' and `cashiers_User` = '".$UserID."'";

    $objQueryCashierID = mysql_query($GetCashierID) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
    $GetCashierIDResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQueryCashierID);
    $BillsCashierID = $GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_CashierID'];
    $CashierTotal = $GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_Total'];
    $CashierLastTotal = $GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_Last_Total'];
    $num = mysql_affected_rows();

    // Return Data
    return $cashier_data = array('cashierId'        => $BillsCashierID ,
                                 'CashierTotal'     => $CashierTotal ,
                                 'CashierLastTotal' => $CashierLastTotal);
}
```

Now when calling this function `GetCashierDetail (11)`, I need to print the `$cashier_data` on variable like this:

```
$ID = $BillsCashierID
```

To using it on other way.

I will try:

```
class Bills {

    // Get Cashier ID
    function GetCashierDetail ($ausers_ID){

        $GetCashierID = "SELECT cashiers_CashierID,cashiers_Total,cashiers_Last_Total
                         FROM `cashiers`
                         WHERE `cashiers_CashierCloseDate` is null and `cashiers_Status`='0'
                         and `cashiers_Delete` = '0' and `cashiers_User` = '".$UserID."'";
        $objQueryCashierID = mysql_query($GetCashierID) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
        $GetCashierIDResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQueryCashierID);
        $BillsCashierID = $GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_CashierID'];
        $CashierTotal = $GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_Total'];
        $CashierLastTotal = $GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_Last_Total'];
        $num = mysql_affected_rows();
        // Return Data
        return $cashier_data = array('cashierId'        => $BillsCashierID ,
                                     'CashierTotal'     => $CashierTotal ,
                                     'CashierLastTotal' => $CashierLastTotal);
    }

}

$BillDraftSubmit = new Bills();
$data = $BillDraftSubmit->GetCashierDetail(71);
$cashierId = $data["cashierId"];
$CashierTotal = $data["CashierTotal"];
$CashierLastTotal = $data["CashierLastTotal"];
echo "cashierId" . $cashierId;
echo "<br>CashierTotal" . $CashierTotal;
echo "<br>CashierLastTotal" . $CashierLastTotal;
```

But I cannot get a result.

Comment: `$id =  $cashier_data['cashierId']`

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$arr = GetCashierDetail (11);
extract($arr);
print $cashierId." ".$CashierTotal." ".$CashierLastTotal;
```

Comment: Not mainstream solution :P +1

Comment: @Sam: I believe it's closely related to my wordpress addiction where it's used very often ;)

Comment: Better defense to use `list($cashierId, $CashierTotal, $CashierLastTotal) = GetCashierDetail(11);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$return = GetCashierDetail(11);
$id = $return['cashierId'];
```

RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

just return the array, no need to assign it to anything. i.e.

```
return array('cashierId'=>$BillsCashierID ,
                      'CashierTotal'=>$CashierTotal ,
                      'CashierLastTotal'=>$CashierLastTotal );
```

or do

```
$cashier_data = array('cashierId'=>$BillsCashierID ,
                      'CashierTotal'=>$CashierTotal ,
                      'CashierLastTotal'=>$CashierLastTotal ); 
return $cashier_data;
```

then when you return it with `$cd = GetCashierDetail(1);` you can access `$cd['CashierTotal']`

Comment: but this function is function on class named Bills, How can i get the result

Answer (score 0):

Why not return just an array?

```
        function GetCashierDetail ($UserID){
    $GetCashierID = "SELECT cashiers_CashierID,cashiers_Total,cashiers_Last_Total 
    FROM `cashiers` 
    WHERE `cashiers_CashierCloseDate` is null and `cashiers_Status`='0' 
    and `cashiers_Delete` = '0' and `cashiers_User` = '".$UserID."'";
    $objQueryCashierID = mysql_query($GetCashierID) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
    $GetCashierIDResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQueryCashierID);
    $BillsCashierID = $GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_CashierID'];
    $CashierTotal=$GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_Total']; 
    $CashierLastTotal=$GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_Last_Total']; 
    $num=mysql_affected_rows();
    // Return Data
    return array('cashierId'=>$BillsCashierID ,
                      'CashierTotal'=>$CashierTotal ,
                      'CashierLastTotal'=>$CashierLastTotal );                      

}  

$user = GetCashierDetail($id);
$ID = $user['cashierId'];
echo $ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//$UserID - your user's id
$result = GetCashierDetail ($UserID);
//now just using as normal array, for example
echo $result['cashierId'];
```

Comment: but this function is function on class named Bills, How can i get the result, i try this   $BillDraftSubmit = new Bills;
$BillDraftSubmit->GetCashierDetail(71);

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to display value of Cashier ID.

You can do it like this..

```
$cashierData = GetCashierDetail(11);

$ID = $cashierData['cashierId'];

echo 'cashier ID is: ' . $ID;
```

Similarly you can also get CashierTotal by `$cashierData['CashierTotal']` and so on

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I gut you right...

```
list($id,,) = GetCashierDetail(11);

echo $id;
```

Comment: The commas are superfluous.