# print value from function on class

Tags: php

i have this function on class called Bills that return three value when calling it.

```
function GetCashierDetail ($UserID){
        $GetCashierID = "SELECT cashiers_CashierID,cashiers_Total,cashiers_Last_Total 
        FROM `cashiers` 
        WHERE `cashiers_CashierCloseDate` is null and `cashiers_Status`='0' 
        and `cashiers_Delete` = '0' and `cashiers_User` = '".$UserID."'";
        $objQueryCashierID = mysql_query($GetCashierID) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
        $GetCashierIDResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQueryCashierID);
        $BillsCashierID = $GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_CashierID'];
        $CashierTotal=$GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_Total']; 
        $CashierLastTotal=$GetCashierIDResult['cashiers_Last_Total']; 
        $num=mysql_affected_rows();
        // Return Data
        return $cashier_data = array('cashierId'=>$BillsCashierID ,
                          'CashierTotal'=>$CashierTotal ,
                          'CashierLastTotal'=>$CashierLastTotal );                      

}
```

now when call this function

```
$BillDraftSubmit = new Bills;
$BillDraftSubmit->GetCashierDetail(71);
```

i need to print the $cashier_data on variable like this

$ID = $BillsCashierID
to using it on other way.

how can i read the value from this function from class

Comment: Why are you asking the same question as 30 minutes ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166127/return-multiple-value-from-function

Comment: no its different here is class and the last it function :)

Comment: its better to read more about PHP basics (Array and object) then going to other advanced step...

Answer (score 0):

**If it is a method** you can use this:

```
$BillDraftSubmit = new Bills();
$data=$BillDraftSubmit->GetCashierDetail(71);
$id=$data["cashierId"];
```

Be careful, because in you question you have

```
$BillDraftSubmit = new Bills;
```

instead of

```
$BillDraftSubmit = new Bills();
```

**If it is not a method** you can use this:

```
$data=GetCashierDetail(71);
$id=$data["cashierId"];
```

Comment: i try but i cannot get result

Comment: Is it a class or just a normal function?

Comment: @ZamalekUwkp, I updated my answer for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

your $ID should have the array in it

use

```
foreach($ID as $key => $val) {
 echo $val['cashierId'];
 ....
 }
```